# Twilio Video + Parse

Tags: ios, swift, twilio

im building an App with Twilio-Video  (https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video). I did  usermanagement-Database with parse but i have problem with access token.

When my user sign up in my app i want to assign twilio access token to their username - the question is how can i do that? or is it with parse not possible? do i need extra backend server for my app  ? Im little bit confused.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/guide/identity

Thanks!

Comment: Is Parse absolutely required here, you know [it's shutting down](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/moving-on/) right? I can help, I just need to know where you're at.

Comment: i know, i deplyoed parse on heroku. if i want to test my app i have to generate Access tokens with twillio testing tool.what i dont understand is, how can i build  with Parse-Database  - easy registration for my user - username, password, location and assign them access tokens. - because without it  they can communicate with twilio. I have no idea how can i generate tokens for user when they sign up. @philnash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

As you've mentioned you're using the Parse server on Heroku, I believe I can help!

You don't actually want to create an access token for [Twilio Video](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video) when a users signs up to your application. Tokens are configurable and can last up to 24 hours. So you want to generate tokens when a user needs one.

Parse server is a Node.js based server and [can be embedded within an Express server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse-server#parse-server--express). Once you do that you can then install the latest [Twilio npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twilio) and use it to generate tokens for your users from an Express endpoint.

The code required to generate a token looks a bit like this:

```
var AccessToken = require('twilio').AccessToken;
var IpMessagingGrant = AccessToken.IpMessagingGrant;

// Used when generating any kind of tokens
var twilioAccountSid = 'ACxxxxxxxxxx';
var twilioApiKey = 'SKxxxxxxxxxx';
var twilioApiSecret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx';

// Used specifically for creating IP Messaging tokens
var serviceSid = 'ISxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
var appName = 'HipFlowSlackDockRC';
var identity = 'user@example.com';
var deviceId = 'someiosdeviceid';
var endpointId = appName + ':' + identity + ':' + deviceId;

// Create a "grant" which enables a client to use IPM as a given user,
// on a given device
var ipmGrant = new IpMessagingGrant({
    serviceSid: serviceSid,
    endpointId: endpointId
});

// Create an access token which we will sign and return to the client,
// containing the grant we just created
var token = new AccessToken(twilioAccountSid, twilioApiKey, twilioApiSecret);
token.addGrant(ipmGrant);
token.identity = identity;

// Serialize the token to a JWT string
console.log(token.toJwt());
// For your app you want to return the token to the front end somehow.
```

For more information, check out the [Twilio API reference for creating access tokens](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/access-tokens#creating-tokens).

Comment: thanks for your Answer.  I deployed Parse Server (https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example) on Heroku. My app is done but i still dont understand how can i now generate tokens with this Twilio npm module from parse? Can u explain it again please ?

Comment: OK, what have you done to try to generate a token so far? Have you tried to use the code from my answer?

Comment: sorry for my late reaction, i was on Vacation.    So my first Question - can i generate tokens with Twilio Trial account or do i have to upgrade my Account first? I ask because i cant find these Infos - twilioAccountSid, twilioApiKey, twilioApiSecret.  I deployed Parse with this Link github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example. What should i do as next step? Sorry fot these stupid questions but im still newbie.

Comment: No problem! You can find your Account SID under the Account Summary in your [Twilio console](https://www.twilio.com/console). You can create an API Key and API Secret in the [dev tools section](https://www.twilio.com/console/dev-tools/api-keys).